Facebook Login for Business Not Granting Permissions
I have a Facebook Login for Business button setup and when I have users of other businesses test it out, it does not grant them permissions that have been defined in the associated configuration id. Instead of granting the users all 5 permissions stated within the configuration it instead only grants them 'public_profile' and 'business_management'.
During developer testing a developer had access to the main Business as well as a client Business to verify that the process worked. When this user login's in and authorises, they are granted all 5 permissions. I have scoured the documentation and am unsure if I'm missing a step or some code.
I am unable to ask Facebook for help as they no longer accept GraphApi problems via their helpdesk. You can only post it on their public error forum in hopes that somebody else can chime in.
If it helps, the login button setup I am using is as follows:
<div
    id="facebook-login-button"
    className="fb-login-button"
    data-width=""
    data-size="medium"
    data-button-type=""
    data-layout=""
    data-auto-logout-link="false"
    data-use-continue-as="false"
    data-config_id={facebookConfigurationId}
    data-onlogin="onFacebookLogin"
></div>


Sounds like so far you only have Standard access to the permissions you are asking for, and not Advanced. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/access-levels

@CBroe's comment was correct. The issue was that were were using the AdAccountId to call the Marketing API in order to retrieve the BusinessId. We did not have Advanced Access for ads_management which is required for the Marketing API
